# How to configure Qt Creator to use devtoolset-2 from RH on centos 6.7?

Tags: c++, qt, centos, qt-creator, devtoolset

I have installed the devtoolset-2 package on my Centos 6.7 64 bits. As recommanded by RH,when i want to switch from gcc 4.4.7 to gcc 4.8.2, i open a terminal and type either `scl enable devtoolset-2 'bash'` if i wanna run gcc in another shell or `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/enable` if i wanna run gcc in the current shell and this works just fine.

Now i would like to use gcc 4.8.2 from Qt 5.7 , so i set up a new Kit and add the new compiler version by adding the path to the g++ and gcc compilers located in `/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++` ( same for gcc ) in compilers paths. And i am able to run the elastic node example using the new Kit to build it.

But i still have a doubt on this procedure because from Qt Creator, i am not using the command `scl enable devtoolset-2 'bash'` or `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/enable`, only add compilers path, so is it the right way to use devtoolset-2 with Qt ?

Answer (score 0):

you can run one of those commands

```
scl enable devtoolset-2 'bash'
```

and

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/enable
```

by adding them into building steps before qmake execution.